# Firefox 67 Bookmarks Toolbar disappeared

Tags: firefox, bookmarks

I have a problem: my bookmarks toolbar disappeared in Firefox 67.

I have the "bookmarks toolbar" option checked and I tried to drag "Bookmarks menu" from Customize on the dash, but it is just not here. I use Arch Linux 5.1.4 with Gnome 3.32. Before this happened, I clicked an ad link which opened in a new window and I accidentally closed the main window. Then I closed the ad window. When I started Firefox again, it showed me the ad window (I use the "open previous sites on start" option) without my bookmarks toolbar. I have not found a way to get the bookmarks toolbar back.

How can I reactivate the bookmarks toolbar?

Comment: I have the same Problem with Firefox 67 on Ubuntu 18.04. Interestingly, the bookmarks toolbar appears in private windows. It seems not connected to add-ons, as the toolbar is also missing when I start Firefox with add-ons disabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Ubuntu 18.04, the issue is fixed after update to Firefox 68.0.